# Questions about the multi-dimension array in Java and C#?

Tags: c#, java, c, multidimensional-array

In the Java or C# programming languages, we can declare the multi-dimension array like below:

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
arr[0] = new int[3];
arr[1] = new int[4];
```

I wanna know the memory allocation mechanism inside the code, especially the difference between them and the C programming language?

Comment: being curious is great, but why do you want to know?

Comment: what do you mean by memory allocation mechanism? one thing you should understand is that C#, Java run on a virtual runtime, while C is compiled to native. the virtual machine uses the same calls as the compiled code. So the actual memory allocation is the same for all the three. But within the runtime, they have different memory allocation mechanisms..

Comment: for memory size used, check the method in C# called sizeof

Comment: The memory allocation mechanism in C is much the same. The only difference is that C supports both arrays of pointers to arrays and arrays or arrays.  Java and C# support arrays of references to arrays.

Answer (score 5):

I can only talk from a Java perspective, but I believe C# works in much the same way (someone please correct me if this is not the case).

There's a difference between declaring and allocating an array and what is done at what point in execution.

When you declare a variable of array type it holds a reference to an object. This doesn't create an array object or allocate space for its components, just the variable itself. But the initialiser can create an array, which then becomes the initial value of the variable. For example:

```
//only has a variable of firstArray (i.e. doesn't create array,
//therefore array memory not used)

int[] firstArray; 

//creates variable secondArray and allocates 4 int
//values to the array

int[] secondArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Reference: [(§10.2) JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html)

When an array is allocated without specific values, all elements receive the default value of the array's data type (e.g. for boolean it will be false, 0 for int, etc.) For example:

```
//Creates an array of 5 Object's which will all
//be null.

Object[] objectArray = new Object[5];
```

Reference: [(§8.3)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#40898) & [(§10.2)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html) JLS

Here's some multi-dimensional array examples too:

```
//This is allocating an int[] array inside myArray at position [0]
int[][] myArray = { { 1, 2 } };

for (int[] i : myArray)
    for (int j : i)
      System.out.println(j);  //will print 1 then 2;
```

To use one of your examples:

```
//This is declaring a multi-dimensional array of int with a max length of 2
int[][] arr = new int[2][]; //Only declaration, no memory allocation for array components

arr[0] = new int[] {1, 2};  //Allocating memory
arr[1] = new int[] {3, 4};  //Allocating memory

for(int[] i : arr)
  for(int j: i)
    System.out.println(j);  //Will print 1 then 2 then 3 then 4...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using constants the compiler (should) coalesce all the requests into one allocation and simply create a static block in the executable itself (.bss section) to reserve memory for the array. For dynamic allocation there's probably the (behind the scenes) use of malloc to allocate the memory for the array. For dynamically sized arrays languages such as C# and Java also have other metadata that needs to be stored such as size so I can't really tell you exactly how much memory it will use. I believe static sized arrays also require sized because of runtime bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but Java virtual machine has own instruction for allocating multidimensional arrays. See *multianewarray* from the [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc9.html).

If you call `new int[1][2][]` the compiler generates byte code having *multianewarray* instruction with dimensions 1 and 2 and the type is int[][][].

Answer (score 0):

in Java, all these allocation are on the heap, so your code is identical to the C code:

```
int **arr=malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
arr[0]=malloc(3*sizeof(int));
arr[1]=malloc(4*sizeof(int));
```

edit: I'm not a Java expert, but I think that in Java, members of new array are initialized to 0 (or null), so calloc is more correct than malloc (in my code).